# Native express ads out of bounds

Tags: android, listview, admob, native-ads

I implemented admob express ads in my application. I use them in listview and are implemented like this:

```
  NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(activityContext);
        AdSize adSize = new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 150);
        adView.setAdSize(adSize);
        adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                adSize.getHeightInPixels(activityContext));

        adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        adQueue.add(adView);
```

In the listview adapter they are then shown just by returning the adview. 
It works normaly but when scrolling for the first time the ad goes out of the view bounds and then in drops back in and works normally after that.

I am not really sure how to explain it so I made a gif:

[image]